# Problemas para iniciar sesión

Tags: php

Tengo un loguen en el cual al ingresar un usuario y contraseña me redirecciona al home.

El problema es que, por alguna razón, el usuario de prueba que creé (usuario: admin, contraseña: 1234) ya no me redirecciona al home, si no que me devuelve a la página de logueo.

Puedo crear otra cuenta e ingresar pero, ¿por qué pasa esto?.

PD: He comprobado si está bien escrito y el usuario, sigue en la base de dato

controlador

```
function iniciarSecion(){

            session_start();
            //libreria para evitar inyecciones
            $_POST = control($_POST);
            if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){               
                if ($this->model->select($_POST)){
                    header('location:'. constant('URL').'home');
                    //$this->view->render('home/index');
                }
                else{
                    header('location:'. constant('URL').'');
                } 
            }
            else {
                header('location:'. constant('URL').'');
            }


        }
```

modelo

```
public function select($array){
            //ingresa los datos de la base de datos
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = ?";
            $resultado = $this->db->conexion()->prepare($sql);
            try{
                $resultado->execute(array($array['usuario']));
                $_SESSION = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if (password_verify($array['contrasenia'], $_SESSION['contrasenia'])) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //echo 'Clave incorrecta';
                    session_destroy();
                    return false;
                }
                
            } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código? Sin código no se puede solucionar el problema, por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/420450/edit) y añade tu código

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente **nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. No disponemos de dotes adivinatorias, por lo que sin código fuente no sabemos qué estás haciendo mal o cómo ayudarte a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. no tengo problema con el código, hasta el este incidente andaba perfectamente, puedo crear nuevos usuarios, cerrar sesión e ingresarlo nuevamente sin problemas, pero la primera cuenta de prueba no puedo ingresarla.